# Group by, having and order by in a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ABC with 2 of its columns, `PIN` and `FROM_DATE`. 
I want to Group by `PIN` having `count > 1` and also want to arragne the result set on `FROM_DATE` column.
I tried,

```
SELECT pin, from_date, COUNT(*) AS repetition 
from ABC
GROUP BY pin
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY from_date;
```

The above statement is giving me `'not a GROUP BY expression'` error.
How to put all `Group by`, `having` and `order by` in a single `select` statement?

Comment: `from_date` in the `SELECT` clause is invalid. It must also be present in the `GROUP BY` clause (or otherwise used as an argument of an aggregate function, like `COUNT()`, `SUM()` etc). In fact, the database engine also tells you the same thing in the error message you posted. It is invalid because the records that have the same value for `pin` (they land in the same group) might have different values for `from_date` and your query does not specify what value to pick for the `SELECT` expression "from_date".

Comment: *"I want to Group by PIN having count > 1 and also want to arragne the result set on FROM_DATE column"* -- this is not what you want. This is the SQL way (kindof) to achieve what you want. Try to express the expected output in plain English, without using SQL concepts. Forget that you are a developer, think as a user.

Comment: If I put the from_date in the select clause, I get no result set. I want to group by PIN and i want to arrange the group on from_date column.

Comment: What `from_date` do you want? All of the dates for each `pin` or only the latest date for each `pin` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the latest `from_date` for each `pin` then:

```
SELECT pin,
       MAX( from_date ) AS from_date,
       COUNT(*) AS repetition 
FROM   ABC
GROUP BY pin
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY from_date;
```

If you want the each distinct `from_date` for each `pin` where there are two or more of those `from_date`s then:

```
SELECT pin,
       from_date,
       COUNT(*) AS repetition 
FROM   ABC
GROUP BY pin, from_date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY from_date;
```

If you want all of the `from_date`s when there are two or more per `pin` then you can use an analytic function:

```
SELECT pin,
       from_date
FROM   (
  SELECT pin,
         from_date,
         COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY pin ) AS repetition 
  FROM   ABC
)
WHERE repetition > 1
ORDER BY from_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT pin, MAX(from_date), COUNT(*) AS repetition 
from ABC
GROUP BY pin
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY MAX(from_date);
```

Or

```
SELECT pin, MIN(from_date), COUNT(*) AS repetition 
from ABC
GROUP BY pin
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY MIN(from_date);
```

Comment: Edit the answer, select the code and use the `{}` button to format it as code. Also explain what output produce each of the queries you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use select columns without aggregation function and not mentioned in group by clause 
so  you could use a subquery for get the values you need and join to values not in group by

```
select distinct ABC.pin, ABC.from_date, t.repetition 
from ABC 
inner join  ( 
SELECT pin, COUNT(*) AS repetition 
from ABC
GROUP BY pin
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) t on t.pin = ABC.pin 
order by ABC.from_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 un-aggregated attributes in your select clause: `pin, from_date` but are only grouping by one of them (pin) hence from_date is 'not a GROUP BY expression'

Consider:

```
 SELECT pin, from_date, COUNT(*) AS repetition 
 from ABC
 GROUP BY pin, from_date
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY from_date;
```